# Este código é O(n)?

Tags: c, complexidade-de-algoritmo

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int maior(int n, int A[]){
    if(n==1)
        return A[0];
    if(maior(n-1, A)<A[n-1])
        return A[n-1];
    else
        return maior(n-1,A);
}
int main(){
    int n, i;
    printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int A[n];
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        A[i] = rand();
        printf("%d\n", A[i]);
    }
    printf("O maior valor é: %d", maior(n, A));
}
```

Este código é O(n)?

E ele é o melhor código recursivo para procurar o maior valor dentro de um vetor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não! Ele tem um bug que faz com que ele seja [image: O(2^n)].

Vamos ver a função `maior`:

```
int maior(int n, int A[]){
    if(n==1)
        return A[0];
    if(maior(n-1, A)<A[n-1])
        return A[n-1];
    else
        return maior(n-1,A);
}
```

Observe que, se `n != 1`, chamamos a função `maior` recursivamente passando o mesmo array, mas como se tivesse um elemento a menos (com o `n` uma unidade menor). Se ele não entrar no `if` e cair no `else`, a função `maior` será chamada uma segunda vez. Isso significa que cada chamada a `maior` pode disparar duas outras e cada uma delas poderá chamar mais duas (totalizando quatro), que por sua vez poderão criar mais duas cada (totalizando oito), etc e só vai parar quando o `n` chegar a 1. Ou seja, cresce exponencialmente.

A solução é armazenar o valor de `maior` em uma variável para chamá-la recursivamente apenas uma vez:

```
int maior(int n, int a[]) {
    if (n == 1) return a[0];
    int m = maior(n - 1, a);
    if (m < a[n - 1])
        return a[n - 1];
    else
        return m;
}
```

E isso pode ser simplificado para isso:

```
int maior(int n, int a[]) {
    if (n == 1) return a[0];
    int m = maior(n - 1, a);
    return m < a[n - 1] ? a[n - 1] : m;
}
```

Essas duas implementações consistem de uma chamada recursiva à `maior` com mais algumas operações que são [image: O(1)] em cada chamada. Vez que a cada chamada, o tamanho de `n` diminui em 1 até chegar em 1, haverá [image: n] chamadas, e aí sim isso será [image: O(n)].

O `for` no `main` é [image: O(n)] também, obviamente.

Comment: Cara, valeu mesmo, estava achando estranho um O(n) demorar tanto quando colocava um número grande pro vetor, mas achei que a demora era por conta do for que preenchia a matriz. O que também não faz sentido. Valeu.